# Twitter log-in - Completed sign-in but not being redirected to my app

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

as the title describes, it stuck on that state.
i didnt find a solution searching the net. 
no error exist...
working with ios swift

image (Hebrew) attached:
it basically says : "redirecting you back to the app, it might take a few moments.."

[image: 'Youre being redirected' page]

Code: 
    AppDelegate -

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    Fabric.with([Twitter.self])

    return true
}


//deprecaed - for support
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let directedByFB = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let directedByGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
    return directedByFB || directedByGoogle
}


func application(application:UIApplication, openURL url: URL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    if Twitter.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options) {
        return true
    }
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue])
}
```

SocialChooserViewController - 
     TWTRAPIClient completion callback is nit being called.. (its not redirecting back to my app)

```
@IBAction func continueLoginWithTwitter() {
    Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn(withMethods: [.webBased]) { session, error in
        guard session != nil else {
            print("error connecting with Twitter: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
            return
        }
        self.chosenMedia = .twtr
        let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session!.userID)
        client.loadUser(withID: session!.userID) { (unwrappedTwtrUser, error) in
            guard let twtrUser = unwrappedTwtrUser, error == nil else {
                print("Twitter : TwTRUser is nil, or error has occured: ")
                print("Twitter error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            _ = self.user.set(firstAndFamilyName: twtrUser.name)
            self.user.set(imageURL: twtrUser.profileImageMiniURL)
            self.user.set(token: session!.authToken)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileVC", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Secondary: 
as further to what i have asked i would also want to change the name of the app bieng presented on permission page, how to do it?

Permission page :

[image]

Comment: inserted the code =]

Comment: the methid is caled or not `application(application:UIApplication, openURL url` after successful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ANSWER: 
there is more updated method at the delegate, 
twitter was calling the deprecated method (as you can see above) but i didnt actually handled twitter inside - so no everything is under the updated method and works just fine and organized:

```
func application(_ application:UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
    print("called")
    let directedByFB = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options)
    let directedByTWTR =  Twitter.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options)
    let directedByGGL =  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    return directedByGGL || directedByTWTR || directedByFB
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
From ios13 we have scenedelegate file so for that with appdelegate openURL method we also need to manage the method in scenedelegate file via the below delegate method for twitter.  

`func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        if let openURLContext = URLContexts.first{
          let url = openURLContext.url
          let options: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation : openURLContext.options.annotation as Any,
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication : openURLContext.options.sourceApplication as Any,
            UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.openInPlace : openURLContext.options.openInPlace
          ]
          TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Selected answer for Swift 4.1 - Xcode 9.3

Podfile

```
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

AppDelegate

```
import FacebookCore
import TwitterKit
import GoogleSignIn

...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
   let directedByFB = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
   let directedByTWTR =  TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options)
   let directedByGGL =  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
     .handle(url,
          sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
          annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
   )
   return directedByFB || directedByTWTR || directedByGGL
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in Xcode 12 in iOS 14.

Actually **My Login button's class was TWTRLogInButton.**
So **I replaced it with UIButton type**. Then I was quickly redirected to my App.

Eg:- Replace

```
@IBOutlet weak var twitterLoginButton: TWTRLogInButton!
```

with

```
@IBOutlet weak var twitterLoginButton: UIButton!
```